# Reply to a question with "Yes, it is" or "No, it is"

Tags: grammar, negation

What is the correct response to the following question:
**Ten divided by five is not two?**

1) Yes, it is.
 2) No, it is.

Intuitively I would say "Yes, it is", but then I thought about it in the following way:

If one asks "Ten divided by five is two?" I would say "Yes, it is", but if the
person asks "Ten divided by five is **not** two?" then I would say "No, it is".

So I think my intuitive answer is wrong, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think it comes down to whether you are arguing or correcting.  You can argue with them using "Yes it is!" or you can correct them using, "No, it (actually) is."

Comment: Note that "Is ten divided by five not two?" would be more idiomatically correct.